# Why can't I assign a function to a variable?

Tags: c++, unsigned-char

If I have the following code example:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


unsigned char Receive(void){
    unsigned char q[4] = {0x0B, 0x0B, 0x0B, 0x0B};
    return q;
}

void Transmit(){
    unsigned char a[4];
    a = Receive();
}

int main()
{
    Transmit();


    return 0;
}
```

Then why can't I assign the return value of `Receive(void)` to the variable q when they both are unsigned char?

### EDIT(see my comment below):

```
unsigned char Receive(void){
    array<unsigned char, 4> q{{0x0B, 0x0B, 0x0B, 0x0B}}
    return q;
}

void Transmit(){
    array<unsigned char, 4> a;
    a = Receive;
}
```

Comment: `a` is an array. `Receive` returns an `unsigned char`, not an array.

Comment: `q` is **not** an `unsigned char` in `Receive()`.

Comment: If you want your code to work as you believe it should, use `std::array<unsigned char, 4>`, not plain arrays.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie
Like in my edit? It doesn't work..

Comment: You are returning an array.  Thus your function return type should be a `std::array`.  Or are you confused as to what you should really be returning?  Are you to return one number, or an array of numbers?

Comment: A collection of four numbers is not the same kind of thing as one number. There is a list of good books [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: I want to return an array of numbers.

Comment: Slow down. Take a moment. Look at the code. Think about what you're returning, and what the return type should be. Take your time.

Comment: `Receive()` generates a warning: **error: invalid conversion from 'unsigned char*' to 'unsigned char' [-fpermissive]**. Do you have enabled the compiler's warnings (such as -Wall -Wextra for gcc & clang)?

Comment: You need to understand the difference between a *single* value and an array of values.  The function return type is a *single* value, but the code returns many values (an array).

Answer (score 1):

> Why can't I assign [result of] a function to a variable?

Because the types don't match. The function returns an `unsigned char`, while the type of the variable is `unsigned char [4]`. Latter is not assignable with the former. In fact, nothing can be assigned to an array.

Answer (score 1):

You really don't want to return an array.  Returning an array causes the compiler to make copies of the array (which slows things down).

The preferred method is to pass a pointer:

```
unsigned char const *  Receive()
{
    static const unsigned char values[] = {0xf0, 0x0d};
    return &values[0];
}
```

The problem here is that the capacity of the array is not returned.  A pointer to the first element is returned, but that is all.

You could pass an array and have the compiler copy all the elements:

```
std::array<unsigned char, 4> Receive()
{
    std::array<unsigned char, 4> q{{0x0B, 0x0B, 0x0B, 0x0B}};
    return q;
}
```

Another method is to pass a `std::vector` by reference:

```
void Receive(std::vector<uint8_t>& container)
{
   container.push_back(0x08);
   container.push_back(0x0B);
   //...
}

void Function()
{
    std::vector<uint8_t> data;
    Receive(data);
    //...
}
```

Passing by reference eliminates the need to copy the data structure.  The function modifies the caller's variable directly.